# Custom UITableViewCell in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have `UITableView` and `UISearchDisplayController`. UITableViewCell is a custom cell with **rowHeight = 30**:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    UILabel *lbTitle;
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];

        lbTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.rowHeight)];
        [lbTitle setTag:1];
        [lbTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Sinhala Sangam MN" size:14]];
        //[lbTitle setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [cell addSubview:lbTitle];
    }
    else {
        lbTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    }
}
```

How to apply this cell style in UISearchDisplayController. Because when search is "active" UISearchDisplayController's cell looks like basic.

[image: list] [image: filtered list]

Thanks

**SOLVED** by the help of MarkM's answer ([Is there a way to customize UISearchDisplayController cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620390/is-there-a-way-to-customize-uisearchdisplaycontroller-cell)):

```
static NSString *normalCellReuseIdentifier = @"ANormalCell";
static NSString *searchCellReuseIdentifier = @"ASearchCell";

UITableViewCell* cell = nil;
UILabel *lbTitle;
if (tableView != self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:normalCellReuseIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:normalCellReuseIdentifier];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];

        lbTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.rowHeight)];
        [lbTitle setTag:1];
        [lbTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Sinhala Sangam MN" size:14]];
        //[lbTitle setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [cell addSubview:lbTitle];
    }
    else lbTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
} else {
    tableView.rowHeight = 30;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:searchCellReuseIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:searchCellReuseIdentifier];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];

        lbTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.rowHeight)];
        [lbTitle setTag:1];
        [lbTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Sinhala Sangam MN" size:14]];
        //[lbTitle setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [cell addSubview:lbTitle];
    }
    else lbTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
}
```

Comment: Couldn't get it.Can you elaborate more specifically with images

Comment: left screen is a list of data, and right screen is a filtered list. I need "searchCell"(in the right) looks like cell in the left ))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620390/is-there-a-way-to-customize-uisearchdisplaycontroller-cell All of the same methods are called. Just compare to searchController.searchResultsTableView

Comment: Awesome. ;-) I added an answer if you'd like to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the same UITableView delegate methods are called with the searchResultsTableView. Please reference the following answer for a more detailed explanation.

[Is there a way to customize UISearchDisplayController cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620390/is-there-a-way-to-customize-uisearchdisplaycontroller-cell)

Answer (score 0):

On your instance of `UISearchDisplayController` (assuming it's called myUISearchDisplayController) call `myUISearchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.rowHeight = 30;`

Answer (score 0):

When `UISearchDisplayController` takes control of the table to display the results, it will call

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

To display the cell, so the only thing you have to do is detect when the displayController is calling this method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if ([tableView isMemberOfClass:[UITableView class]])
    //This is the table view
    else
    //This is the display controller
```

Do the same with the rest of tghe methods of the delegate/datasource to implemente the search results cells as you want (for example, height or number of rows)

Comment: What makes you think that the UISearchDisplayController's tableView isn't a UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

Search display controller has it's own table in which it shows the data which is searching.You can set the height by using this code-

```
SDC.searchResultsTableView.rowHeight = 30;//whatever you want
```

Where SDC is instance of `UISearchDisplayController`

Answer (score 0):

If row height is the only thing to change. setting it with `searchResultsTableView.rowHeight` works only for the first time. Tapping cancel and search with new search key ignore the custom rowHeight. (iOS 6.1, xcode 4.6.1) use the below.

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    tableView.rowHeight = 50.0;
}
```