# Discussion: Best way to implementing a custom search result table view cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to implementing a custom search result table view cell. I have seen people discussing things in threads like [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519656/custom-uitableviewcell-in-uisearchdisplaycontroller).

Finally, I have decided a way to implement this.

[image]

As you can see, I have created to reusable cell in side my UITableView.

So based on the logic

```
if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
```

I will dequeue the reusable cell by the different identifier from self.tableView.

But the problem I discovered right now is the performance.

I find that if I am implementing it in this way, you will find a little bit lag when you scrolling the searchResultTableView which is totally not desired.

So any suggestion for a better implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
You can make Custom Search With NSPredicate Class Like.. 


+(NSArray*) searchByPredicate:(NSString*)filterStr fullArray:(NSMutableArray*)arr{

   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@",filterStr];

    return [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}

Implement This Method Here

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (string.length>0) {
        self.isFilter=YES;
        //filter Predicate use from ReverseStr Class

        NSArray *searchArr=[NSArray searchByPredicate:string fullArray:self.dataArray];
        self.filterArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:searchArr];
        [self.predicateTable reloadData];
    }
    else{
        self.isFilter=NO;
        [self.predicateTable reloadData];
    }


    return YES;
}
```